# Base64 Encode Pylon Sdk Image

Tags: c++, image-processing, base64, jpeg, encode

I am trying to base 64 encode an image grabbed from a Basler camera using pylon sdk.

So after I get the image the code looks like this:

```
formatConverter.Convert(pylonImage, ptrGrabResult);
char *sp = static_cast<char*>(pylonImage.GetBuffer());
vecRes.emplace_back(base64_encode(sp, pylonImage.GetImageSize()));
```

The base64 encoded image should end up beeing displayed on the frontend. But the resulted string doens't look like it should, so something is wrong. Probably I'm not reading the buffer as I should or maybe the buffer requires some processing.

Do you know how I can convert the Pylon image buffer into a base64 encoded image?

Update:
So I think the problem is that the raw byte stream is not jpeg encoded so it can't be displayed on the screen. I tried using jonolick.com/code.html to convert the raw bytes into an image and displayed it but the resulted image when I choose to have 3 channels is wrong. The image gets repeated 3 times on the screen. Do you know how I can encode the raw stream to jpeg format without saving it to disk (the result can be a string with the image content)?

**Closed**:
Resolved the issue in the end. I had to pre-format the basler image in the pylon sdk with PixelType_BGR8packed and then I managed to transform it into jpg with both OpenCv and also https://www.jonolick.com/code.html

Comment: Base64 encoding probably isn't what you want; but just in case it is; did you read the wikipedia article on it?

Comment: Well I choose base64 because it can be easilty displayed on the frontend: data:image/jpeg;base64,${base64EncodedImage}. I know it creates a larger string and adds some overhead but it should not be a problem in my case.Regarding the wiki, I have read it but maybe not so thoroughly. Maybe you can give me a hint on what I should focus if you know what I'm doing wrong. Thank you.

Comment: So I think the problem is that the raw byte stream is not jpeg encoded so it can't be displayed on the screen. I tried using https://www.jonolick.com/code.html to convert the raw bytes into an image and displayed it but the resulted image when I choose to have 3 channels is wrong. The image gets repeated 3 times on the screen. Do you know how I can encode the raw stream to jpeg format without saving it to disk (the result can be a string with the image content)?